# Is asking questions about using machines for language learning on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

This [question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/is-it-possible-to-read-braille-from-vibration-motors) seems quite borderline with on-topic and off-topic. The reason this question us up is because of Flimzy's comment on the question:

> I'm really not sure if this is about language learning. What do others think?

That really is the question. Are these types of questions allowable or not? To be clear on what type of questions are under question here, those questions should be about the *machines* that assist with learning a language. For example, rather than asking what is effective for improving fluency, the question would be about the books that assist in improving fluency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about learning scripts—e.g. Braille—should be acceptable. But since the question is whether "vibration motors [attached to the hands can] be used for" learning Braille, it is about assistive technology and the sense of touch in specific body parts, I consider it out of scope for this website. It is more about the granularity of what be perceived by touch ([haptic perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_perception)), rather than learning Braille as such. It is more about [rehabilitation engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rehabilitation_engineering) than language acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

As Christophe states, questions about learning methods regarding the **acquisition** of Braille are inside the scope of this site. However, questions about the actual mechanics used to create the Braille script involve more technology than language learning, and thus are **off-topic** here.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider "machine" using on topic as long as it relates directly to language learning. For instance, the gist of the "main" question cited in the meta question is, can such-and-such Braille reader to an adequate job of teaching people to read Braille, given its vibration issues?

A question about the machine *itself* would be off-topic; e.g., how do you start up/set up/deploy this machine?